# Nested Tables with pdf generator module Reportlabs

Tags: python, reportlab

So im trying to create nested tables in my pdf generator but there seems to be some overflow in the pdf which I haven't been able to solve

So it seems you cannot let reportlabs take more y axis space in the columns and if the data inside the column it wil just overflow to the sides instead of in height.

Here are the code snippets responsible for creating the tables:

```
def create_table(data: List[List[Union[str, int, float]]], width_percentage: float, 
style: TableStyle) -> Table:
page_width = A4[0]
total_width = page_width * width_percentage

num_columns = len(data[0])
col_width = total_width / num_columns
col_widths = [col_width] * num_columns

table = Table(data, colWidths=col_widths)
table.setStyle(style)
table.splitByRow = 0

return table
```

[image]
[image]

```
NESTED_TABLE = [
      ['example', 'example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example34', 'example5', 
       'example6'],
      [1142131, 214214, 23423, 214, 1523, 24, 214]
 ]

exampledata= [
    [NESTED_TABLE],
    ["some random string of text"]
]

    story.append(create_table(exampledata, 0.9, green_boxes_table()))
```